# QField Tracking problem with Trimble R1

Tags: qgis, qfield, trimble, tracking

I'm using QField on a Samsung Active 3 Tablet which is connected with a Trimble R1. The GNSS Status App provides the mock location.
Previously I had some problems with the R1 positioning me not correctly in the QField. After several attempts, the position matches the georeferenced layer in the field. The accuracy is sometimes less than one metre, sometimes more.But now the position marker jumps back and forth. This is especially a problem when I want to record a polygonal area using the tracking mode. A rectangular area looks very shapeless. More like a star. What could be the cause of the problem? Our previous GPS device (+years) works much more accurately than the Trimble R1.

Comment: Does the R1 connect through Blutetooth? Have you tried connecting it to QField using the built-in BT capabilities of the latest versions (since last December)?

Comment: What happens if you disconnect from the R1 in GNSS Status?  Does GNSS Status get Android Locations every second (look on the GNSS Status Status page, see if the Time field changes every second).  If GNSS Status gets locations every second without the R1, something else is also feeding Android Locations, so when R1 is connected QField may be jumping between R1 positions and "something else" positions.  Disclaimer:  I know nothing about QField, but I know lots about R1 including Android Mock Locations.